# Exchange 2010 OWA with Client Certificates

Tags: security, exchange

I have enabled Client Certificate Authentication for Exchange 2010 through IIS7 and the users are prompted to choose their User Certificate when they log in, but they are all then presented with the following error message

> Request Url: https://<domain_name>:443/owa/ User host address:
>   <server_ip_address> OWA version: 14.1.355.2
>
> Exception Exception type: System.NullReferenceException Exception
>   message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Call stack
>
> Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.RequestDispatcher.GetUserIdentities(OwaContext
>   owaContext, OwaIdentity& logonIdentity, OwaIdentity& mailboxIdentity,
>   Boolean& isExplicitLogon, Boolean& isAlternateMailbox,
>   ExchangePrincipal& logonExchangePrincipal) 
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.RequestDispatcher.InternalDispatchRequest(OwaContext
>   owaContext) 
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.RequestDispatcher.DispatchRequest(OwaContext
>   owaContext) 
>   Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Owa.Core.OwaRequestEventInspector.OnPostAuthorizeRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) 
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&
>   completedSynchronously)

The method I followed to enable Certificate authentiaction was from this post:

http://www.miru.ch/2011/04/how-to-enable-certificate-based-authentication-on-exchange-2010/

Any ideas?  Google isn't being very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was simple, you just need to search for `<authentication mode="Form"/>` in the web.config file and change it to Windows (capital W)

> The authentication type specified in the
>
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange
>   Server\V14\ClientAccess\owa\web.config file is incorrect. The correct
>   authentication type is "Windows".

Comment: What is the OWA authentication mode set to in EMC? Exchange has a tendency to overwrite manually configured values...

Comment: This is a little while ago amigo! I cant remember :)